# httprequest to a webserver returns null json in javasqript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a call to webservice using httpWebRequest but i get the resonse as always null JSON.

```
var con = $.net.http.getConnection("http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo");
con.setProxy("proxy", 8080); 
var resp = con.request("GET", "/Service1.html");

//resp here is always null
```

The output I get is this:

```
 {}
```

Don't really know where I am going wrong.

Help me if you know regarding this.

Comment: It seems like you use a library. What library is that? Also that JavaScript is asynchronous (via a callback) and that you usually can't use XHR cross-domain.